# Conditional probability with correlated random variables

Tags: correlation, conditional-probability

Consider random variables $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$, and $V_4$.

Then, define $U_2=V_1+V_2$ and $U_3=V_1+V_3$. That is, $U_2$ and $U_3$ are correlated by construction.

My first question is whether the following equality can hold:
$$
\Pr\left[U_2<V_4\mid V_4,U_3\right] = \Pr\left[U_2<V_4 \mid V_4\right] \tag1
$$
In my personal opinion, because $U_2$ and $U_3$ are correlated, the equality hoes not hold in general. But, I am not sure.

Second, I am considering an assumption below:
$$\Pr\left[U_2<V_4+U_3\mid V_4,U_3\right] = \Pr\left[U_2<V_4 \mid V_4 \right]. \tag 2$$
Here, again, it is not clear for me that this assumption can be plausible since $U_2$ and $U_3$ are correlated.

Lastly, if the assumption $(2)$ can be plausible, does the assumption $(2)$ imply the equation $(1)$?

Thank you.

Comment: $\Pr\left[U_2<V_4\mid V_4,U_3\right]$ is a function of $U_3$ while $\Pr\left[U_2<V_4\mid V_4\right]$ is not (both are functions of $V_4$), so I am not sure what your $(1)$ is suppose to mean.  There is a similar issue with your $(2)$

Comment: If $V_1,V_2,V_3$ are indepedent and $\operatorname{var}(V_1)>0,$ then $U_2,U_3$ are correlated, but more generally you cannot conclude that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $V_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.5),\,i=1,\dots,4$.  Let $V_4 = 1$; $U_2 < V_4$ iff $U_2 = 0$, which has probability $0.5$, so $\Pr[U_2 < V_4\mid V_4] = 0.5$.

Let $U_3 = 2$, implying that $V_1 = V_3 = 1$.  Clearly $U_2 \geq 1$, so $\Pr[U_2 < V_4\mid V_4, U_3] = 0$, so the first equality does not always hold. As $V_4 + U_3 = 3$, $\Pr[U_2 < V_4+U_3\mid V_4,U_3] = 1$, and the second inequality does not always hold either.

Comment: The typographical effect of `\text{Pr}` is not always the same as that of `\Pr`. With the latter, you get context-dependent horizontal spacing so that you see $2\Pr(A)$ rather than $2\text{Pr}(A).$ Clearly the latter does not have proper spacing.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelHardy - I did not know about the `\Pr` shortcut!

Comment: Notice that it's not just a shortcut. If, for example, you want to write about $2\operatorname{arccsc}\theta,$ it would be incorrect to write `2\text{arccsc}\theta`; rather the correct code would be `2\operatorname{arccsc}\theta`. The former results in $2\text{arccsc}\theta,$ which lacks proper horizontal spacing, and the latter in $2\operatorname{arccsc}\theta,$ with proper spacing. Notice also that with `2\operatorname{arccsc}(\theta)` you see $2\operatorname{arccsc}(\theta),$ and the space to the right of $\operatorname{arccsc}$ is smaller than when the left parenthesis is not there.$\quad$

Comment: I.e., the spacing depends on the context. And that does not happen with `\text{}`. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Huh... now I've learned two things from this question! Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to understand TeX and the softwares that evolved from it, remember that Donald Knuth invented TeX, and unlike most people, he understands things that he works with.